# Currency conversion database structure from text file

Tags: c

I've been working on a program for a data structure that reads in a file of different currencies, which I then call to use for conversion. I've been running over this for days on end and tried `fgets`, `fscanfs`, and such, and I'm just lost at this point as I am pretty new to programming.

the dat. file is outlined on separate lines like this:

```
dollar 1.00

yen 0.0078

franc 0.20

mark 0.68

pound 1.96
```

my code so far:

```
  typedef struct {
   string currency;
   double rate;
   } currencyT;

  typedef struct {
   currencyT cur[MaxCurrencyTypes];
   int nCurrency;
   } *currencyDB;


  static currencyDB ReadDataBase(void);  
  static ReadOneLine(FILE *infile, currencyDB db);  

  static currencyDB ReadDataBase(void)
 {
   FILE *infile;
   currencyDB db;
      int nCurrency;

   db = New(currencyDB);
   infile = fopen(ExchangeFile, "r");
       while (ReadOneLine(infile, db));
   fclose(infile);
   return(db);
 }

  static ReadOneLine(FILE *infile, currencyDB db) 
 {
   currencyT cur;
   char termch, currency;
   double rate;
   int nscan, nCurrency;


   nCurrency = 0;

   while(1) {
       nscan = fscanf(infile, "%20s %f%c", db->cur[nCurrency].currency, 
  &db->cur[nCurrency].rate, &termch);
           if(nscan = EOF) break;
           if(nscan != 3 || termch != '\n') {
               Error("Improper file format");
               }
           nCurrency++;
           }
       db->nCurrency = nCurrency;  
   }


 static void ProcessExchange(currencyDB db)
 {

 }



 main()
 {
   currencyDB currencies;

   currencies = ReadDataBase();

   ProcessExchange(currencies);


 }
```

Comment: Once this goes to SO, edit your question to give more detail about what is going wrong. You will get better feedback that way rather than saying "here is my code, fix it."

Comment: Can you show how the type `string` is defined?

Comment: `if(nscan = EOF) break;` should be `if(nscan == EOF) break;` (= should be ==)

Answer (score 0):

See 8 & 9 first.

1. `MaxCurrencyTypes` is undeclared, let's assume

   ```
   #define MaxCurrencyTypes (5)
   ```
2. `string` is undeclared, let's assume

   ```
   typedef char * string;
   ```
3. `currencyDB` is a pointer type, recommend instead declaring as a structure type

   ```
   typedef struct {
     currencyT cur[MaxCurrencyTypes];
     int nCurrency;
   } currencyDB;  // Drop *
   ```
4. `static ReadOneLine()` should use explicit return type.

   ```
   static int ReadOneLine()
   ```
5. `int nCurrency;` not used in `ReadDataBase()`.
6. `New()` in `db = New(currencyDB)` is not declared nor defined.  Assume to allocate uninitialized memory for `*db`.
7. `ExchangeFile` not declared.
8. `if (nscan = EOF)` -> `if (nscan == EOF)`
9. `ReadOneLine()` needs to return a value.
10. `main()` should explicitly state return type and parameters.

    ```
    int main(void)
    ```